# using variables stored in a file to trigger events

Tags: c#, windows, file

I am very new to C#, well new to file writing and reading of it. anyway I am making a event sequence that will play the events when the timer reaches a number, also in that file the timer will adjust its speed dependent on a number stored in the file as well. how would i go about this, here is the text of that file when decoded.

```
 [EventSequence]
{
    DisplayName "Default"
    OFFset = 0
    Resolution = 192

}
 [SyncSequence]
{
0 = B 180000
}
 [EventsNotes]
{
0 = E "section Intro"
15168 = E "Note1"
21120 = E "Note2"
26880 = E "Note3"
38976 = E "Note4"
44928 = E "Note5"
}
 [Events]
{
192 = N 0 0
240 = N 0 0
288 = N 0 0
336 = N 0 0
384 = N 4 0
432 = N 0 0
480 = N 0 0
528 = N 0 0
576 = N 3 0
624 = N 0 0
672 = N 0 0
720 = N 0 0
768 = N 4 0
816 = N 0 0
864 = N 0 0
912 = N 0 0
960 = N 2 0
1008 = N 0 0
1056 = N 0 0
1104 = N 0 0
1152 = N 1 0
 }
```

the timer will be quite fast but dependent on the value under Sync. the Large Values are the times that will trigger an event, the N 0 0 etc are the events. similar setup for the "event notes. the rest is just basic information. any help or Advice is appreciated in Advanced.

Comment: With what specific part do you have a problem?

Comment: You haven't really asked a question.

Comment: finding the lines between the the labeled sections efficiently e.g if i wanted to use everything in the Events section, i do not want anything from the other sections, and i need it to be available for files of many sizes. the question was "how would i go about this."

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made this function for your case :

```
public List<string> GetFileKeyValues(string fileName, string key)
        {
            List<string> res = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
                {
                    using (System.IO.StreamReader tr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName))
                    {
                        bool keyFound = false;
                        while (!tr.EndOfStream)
                        {
                            string s = tr.ReadLine().ToLower();
                            if (s.Contains(key.ToLower())) keyFound = true;
                            else
                            {
                                if (keyFound)
                                {
                                    if (!s.Contains("{") && !s.Contains("}")) res.Add(s);
                                    if (s.Contains("}")) break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        tr.Close();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            return res;
        }
```

**Usage** let's say we want to get `[SyncSequence]` values so :

```
List<string> res = GetFileKeyValues(@"C:\t.txt", "[SyncSequence]");
if(res != null && res.Count > 0) 
{
  //Do Something with res[0], it will return 0 = B 180000
  //So you split it by "=" to get B 180000 or any thing you want... 
}
```

Comment: thanks, this was exactly what i was looking for. the rest i can handle when it comes to using the values.